# Converting excel formula to javascript problem

Tags: javascript, excel

Formula in excel

```
=AVERAGE($B$20,$C$20)/((PI()/4)*(AF21+0.01)^2)
```

is basically this:

```
=AVERAGE(5000,4500)/((PI()/4)*(0.3859+0.01)^2)
```

Which out puts as 38586

Formula in javascript

```
function calcUltimate(max, min, radius) {
        return (((max + min) / 2) / (Math.pow(((Math.PI / 4) * (radius + 0.01)), 2))).toFixed(0);
    }
```

Output is 49130

I can not get the outputs to match at all. I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Stupid question: are you sure your variables (in JS) match the numbers in your formula?

Comment: Yes I have. Even if i replace my variables with the exact numbers, they still do not match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this please:

```
function calcUltimate(max, min, radius) {
   return parseInt((((max + min) / 2) / ((Math.PI / 4) * Math.pow((radius + 0.01), 2))).toFixed(0));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be (you're putting too much into `Math.pow` call):

```
function calcUltimate(max, min, radius) {
        return (((max + min) / 2) / ((Math.PI / 4) * Math.pow((radius + 0.01), 2))).toFixed(0);
}
```

Comment: Pay attention, your function is returning a String.

Comment: @V.Sambor Which is the same type as the original function.

Answer (score 0):

Your operations are going in the wrong order. To debug formulas simply break them down into separate operations saving the results in different variables. This way you can more easily read the operations going on.

```
function calcUltimate(max, min, radius) {
  var avg = (max + min) / 2;
  var quarterPie = Math.PI / 4;
  var adjustedRadius = radius + 0.01;

  //the adjusted radius is the one being squared
  //** is power, shorter than using Math.POW() for
  //supporting browsers
  var squareAdjustedRadius = adjustedRadius**2;

  //if you don't want the decimal part but still want a number
  return Math.floor( avg / (quarterPie * squreAdjustedRadius) )
  //if you actually want a string version
  return (avg / (quarterPie * squreAdjustedRadius)).toFixed(0)
}
```

Demo

```js
console.log(calcUltimate(5000,4500,0.3859))

function calcUltimate(max, min, radius) {
  var avg = (max + min) / 2;
  var quarterPie = Math.PI / 4;
  var adjustedRadius = radius + 0.01;
  var squareAdjustedRadius = adjustedRadius**2;

  return Math.floor(avg / (quarterPie * squareAdjustedRadius));
}
```